# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException,The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring

[the code of the FileUploadDaoImpl.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOSdS.png)I meet a question when I import a old java project.It is created by Spring and mybatis.I don't know why it's can't work? who can help me.This is the first question in the overstackflow.Thank all of you very much.

信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-10-21 09:07:29,663 ERROR [com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidAbstractDataSource] - maxIdle is deprecated
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [logfile].
2016-10-21 09:07:31,335 INFO [com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource] - {dataSource-1} inited
2016-10-21 09:07:40,569 INFO [com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource] - {dataSource-1} closed
2016-10-21 09:07:40,569 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUpLoadImpl' defined in file [E:\javaProject.metadata.me_tcat\webapps\pre\WEB-INF\classes\com\app\pub\service\impl\FileUpLoadImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.pub.service.impl.FileUpLoadImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4334)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.pub.service.impl.FileUpLoadImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

```
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
... 37 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

```
at com.app.pub.service.impl.FileUpLoadImpl.<init>(FileUpLoadImpl.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 39 more
```

2016-10-21 09:07:40,569 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUpLoadImpl' defined in file [E:\javaProject.metadata.me_tcat\webapps\pre\WEB-INF\classes\com\app\pub\service\impl\FileUpLoadImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.pub.service.impl.FileUpLoadImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you show code of `FileUploadDaoImpl` ?

Comment: I just thinking how to upload the code of FileUploadDaoImpl? It always show error I feel very confused.

Comment: Have you recently switched your java version? Which version you are using currently?

Comment: Now,my java vesion is 1.8.I did't change my java version.But I don't clear that the project is running in 1.8 or 1.7. Maybe  I need learn more and upload my code to you.I will't not upload my code until tonight.Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: I use the Myeclipse.And I upload the code of FileUploadDaoImpl in the picture in the begin of the question's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse:

Right Click on Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Build Path --> Libraries --> Select jdk 1.8.

MyEclipse:

1) Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE’s > click on Add > Select standard VM and click Next > Select the JDK 1.7 directory and click Finish.

2) Clicking on finish will list JDK1.8 under ‘installed JRE’s’ section. Select JDK 1.8 listed and click Ok.
3) Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > select 1.8 from the ‘Compiler compliance level’ drop down list and click ‘Apply’ and Ok

I believe similar can be done on MyEclipse.

Comment: I use your method,But I still could't solve the problems.Let's me be calm.If I deal with it.I will informe of you.

Comment: Today I solve the problem.Totally,the reason is that jdk and jre is in the same document. when I use the jdk of myeclipse itself's.It can't work.I don't know the reason utill today.so I use the outside tomcat7.0.It can't work.The reason is that jdk's name is wrong.through baidu and google,I know the reason is that jdk and jre in the same document.Last,I reinstall the jdk and  jre and solve the problem.

Comment: @kent That's great. Glad, I could help.